# Is an image created in an expression disposed-of immediately?

Tags: c#, dispose, using

Is this enough:

```
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
    {
        g.DrawImage(newImage.GetThumbnailImage(10, 10, null, new IntPtr()), 3, 3, 10, 10);
    }
```

Or should I use:

```
  using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
        {
            using (Image i = newImage.GetThumbnailImage(10, 10, null, new IntPtr()))
            {
                g.DrawImage(i, 3, 3, 10, 10);
            }
        }
```

EDIT:
Can someone please add some MS reference that even when there is no variable created – the resources will not be freed immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not going to be disposed unless you specifically call the `Dispose()` method on it (or it leaves a `using` block). So in your case, using the second `using` block would be the safer choice to make sure you free unmanaged resources.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `using` statement for types that implement `IDisposable`.  Otherwise, the resources won't be freed until the object is finalized.

To make the code a tad neater, I like to stack `using` blocks

```
  using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
  using (Image i = newImage.GetThumbnailImage(10, 10, null, new IntPtr()))
  {
      g.DrawImage(i, 3, 3, 10, 10);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not only will garbage collector not trigger immediatelly, but it might not clear the objects correctly if they hold system resources - like files. I am not sure about Image class though, but still, should your code have to (some day) run on a tight memory, you want image cleaned immediatelly when you are done with it. This is where `using` and `IDisposable` come in.

I found a very good blog once about Using block [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163392.aspx), following code:

```
using (MyClass myClass = GetMyClass())
{
    myClass.DoSomething();
}
```

will behave exactly like this:

```
MyClass myClass = GetMyClass();
try
{
    myClass.DoSomething();
}
finally
{
    IDisposable disposable = myClass as IDisposable;
    if (disposable != null) disposable.Dispose();
}
```

So it will clean your Image even if your code throws and exception, and it will cause no problem if you call dispose yourself.

In short: always use using with objects that implement IDisposable, in addition, if the code is complex, call Dispose yourself as soon as you do not need the object anymore - and set the object reference to null.